# What is the proper syntax for using an object as a class property in excel vba?

Tags: class, excel, vba

I'm trying to use the worksheet object as a property in a vba class module.  Hers' what I have in a a class module called `clsAgent`:

```
Public Property Get AgentSheet() As Worksheet
    Set AgentSheet = pAgentSheet
End Property

' error thrown on next two lines 
Public Property Set AgentSheet(AgentSheet As Worksheet)
    Set pAgentSheet = AgentSheet
End Property
```

When I use the the following code I get a `compile error: Variable not defined" thrown in the class module:

```
Sub test_agent_class()
Dim agent1 As clsAgent
Set agent1 = New clsAgent

agent1.AgentSheetName = "agentsFullOutput.csv"

Set agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets(agent1.AgentSheetName)
Debug.Print agent1.AgentSheet.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add in your `clsAgent` module file the following line:

`Dim pAgentSheet As Worksheet`

since the properties you have created ought to reference an existing `pAgentSheet` field of the `clsAgent` module.

Please try also the modified test file:

```
Sub test_agent_class()

    Dim agent1 As clsAgent
    Set agent1 = New clsAgent

    Set agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets("agentsFullOutput.csv")
    Debug.Print agent1.AgentSheet.Name

End Sub
```

I'm not 100% sure but it looked like you were referencing a variable/property`AgentSheetName` which didn't exist in the `clsAgent` class module.

I hope it helps at least slightly.